# The package org.sqlite conflicts with a package accessible from another module: sqlite.jdbc in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

The following error displayed on **JDBC.java** file while inserting data in sqlite database:

> "The **package org.sqlite** conflicts with a package accessible from another module: **sqlite.jdbc**"

```
package org.sqlite;

import java.sql.Connection;    
import java.sql.Driver;    
import java.sql.DriverPropertyInfo;    
import java.sql.SQLException;    
import java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException;    
import java.util.Properties;    
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class JDBC implements Driver {
```

**How to avoid this error?**

Answer (score 1):

Java does **not allow** to have the **same package in more than one module**.

To avoid this error do one of the following:

- **Rename your package** and make sure to choose a unique name (e.g. `com.my_company.db_connector`)
- Do not use the Java Platform Module System (JPMS) by deleting the `module-info.java` file and move the `sqlite` JAR from the modulepath to the classpath

Comment: Thank you for considering my problem.

I want to ask something more..

When I insert data into SQLite db using Eclipse, without any problem data inserts into db.

But after Exporting Eclipse Project into Android Project, it dosn't work.Data is not inserted into db using Android.Following error displays all the time:

"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: E:\eclipse ws\Student\src\org\sqlite"

Eclipse successfully finds the required package "org.sqlite.JDBC"

Why Android is unable to find the required package?

Please help me regarding this.